# How to define weights in gbm package & Kappa statistic for class imbalanced data set (gbm)

Tags: r, metrics, gbm

I would like to find a way to define weights for gbm in caret package. There is a parameter "weights" in the "train" function for "caret" package but the description says "This argument will only affect models that allow case weights". As per my understanding "gbm" does support defining the weights but I do not know the format of defining weights. Is it simply c(1,10) - where 1 is for majority class and 10 is for minority class?

The second question is on Kappa statistic. I read that Kappa is a better performance metric for class imbalanced data sets but failed to understand how. I will appreciate some guidance on why Kappa is a better performance metric compared to ROC for class imbalanced data set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, `gbm` does support case weights and weights should be a vector the length of the data frame. If you are only using two classes I believe you will **have** to use ROC. I'm not sure I'm qualified to answer your question on ROC vs. Kappa, but [here](http://www.pitt.edu/~jeffcohn/biblio/Jeni_Metrics.pdf) is a paper from 2013 looking at the performance of several metrics on real world data. The general take away seems to be that while kappa can be affected by skew (ROC seems to be relatively immune), ROC tends to mask poor performance.

Comment: Thanks @scribbles. You mentioned that weights need to be a vector and same length as the training data frame. Does that mean I have to define the weight for each observation? or is there a way to define a vector of length (2) and let the algorithm assign one weight to class-1 and other to class-0 in case of a binary classfication problem. Plus, I have not seen a single example where weights are defined for gbm so far. I still appreciate your time for looking into the question.

Comment: @syebill - Yes, the weights need to be a vector the same length as the training data frame (would ideally just be another column in your data frame to avoid any issues), and yes you would have to assign them yourself. Since `gbm` in the `caret` package is essentially a classifying algorithm, it would be impossible for the model to assign both a weight AND classify the objects since by changing the weight you also affect the probability of the classification. In order to include the weights in your model, you would have to add a `weights = df$weights` argument in your `train()` statement.

Answer (score 2):

In this [article](http://dpmartin42.github.io/blogposts/r/imbalanced-classes-part-1) there is an example of the use of `weights`.
In your case, it will be something like

```
data$weights <- ifelse(data$class == "major", 1, 10)
```

Then use this column as the weights.